# OBSOLETE - StackBerry application for BlackBerry

Tags: app, obsolete

## OBSOLETE - website and source code repository are down

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Blackberry screenshot]
<sub>(source: [livinloud.ca](http://livinloud.ca/documents/stackoverflowBB.png))</sub>

### About

I created this app because I always wanted to create an open source application. But I never had an idea on what to do. So I used my skill in BlackBerry development to build an app with the API provided by StackOverflow.

#### License

It's licensed under [GNU General Public License v3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)

#### Download

You can get the source code on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stackberry/), and compile it yourself with [BlackBerry plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp).

#### Platform

BlackBerry OS 5.0
I will try to make it for 4.5+, but since RIM is trying to push OS 5.0 on all devices, I may not do it.

### Contact

Right now I'm the only contributor, you can reach me on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stackberry/)

### Code

I'm using J2ME and BlackBerry API to build the application and the [BlackBerry eclipse Plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp)

### Other

It is still in an alpha stage of development. I don't have much time this summer to finish this application. I will try to do my best to add code every week or two. If people are interested in helping, post your information on the Google Code page.

If people have logo, Application name idea, they are welcome.

This is the first time I show my code online, and I will apreciate any helpful comments on my work.

If you find out that my english is not well written, this is because it is not my first language, feel free to correct me.

The  first version of the app was built during the close beta, but I never had the time to post on the other website for the beta.

### Change log

- It is now supporting the 3 websites.

Thanks.

Comment: Now working with version 1.0 of the API, you can download the source from the project, compile it and test it.

Comment: 5-stars for listing this on StackList! *(No really, it does deserve 5 stars.)*

Comment: @MichaelB. is this app alive? I have a BB 9360 with BB OS 7.1 and like to have this installed! Any way to get a .jar, .jad or install via OTA?

Comment: @ReynierPM I wish I had the time to continue the application, you can get the Code from Google code and compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a great job!

Name ideas:

- stackBerry
- blackStack
- bbStack

The picture makes me wish I had a BlackBerry :)

Comment: I'm secretly hoping you'll pick stackBerry 'cuz it just sounds awesome.

Comment: I'll see if I get other idea and will decide this week-end.

Comment: Wish I had more time, I would do it for Android too :P

Comment: @Michael: Actually, I'm considering an Android app myself.

Answer (score 3):

Good job!  BTW, don't use those suggested names if you don't want nasty-grams from RIM.  They have specific guidelines here: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/legal/BlackBerry_Branding_Guidelines_September_2008_v1.pdf

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the names, I don't use any of their copyright name.

Comment: If you read the referenced PDF, you'll find this in the "Unacceptable" category: [Your Product/Service Name]berry

Answer (score 2):

Am a good java developer, develop in rails and other languages. I dnt mind helping out:D However I want to advice [Github](http://github.com) as its a good version control system.

Comment: You can contact me directly, my email is in my profile.

Comment: dnt think it is cause i cant see it

Comment: infosonic+so at gmail dot com

Answer (score 2):

The application does not work, or at least I cannot install it. I can get the jar file, but the phone gives errors on install. I tried to get the cod files in a different way and install the app offline, but I failed. Is this application valid for Blackberry Curve 8520 OS 5?

Comment: Without the error message I can't help you...

Comment: I managed to install it, but I get the error : "Error starting stackoverflow: Module must be signed with the RIM Runtime Code Signing Key (RRT)"

Comment: It seems I forgot to sign the package, I will have to recompile it.

Comment: Please let me know when it is done. :)